# Including Array of same type in Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a variadic template in c++ which can deduce the type at compile time and provide me with any specified operation. For example, I wish to sum elements of same type passed as argument. This is where I have come so far -

```
template <typename T>
T sum(T &v) { return v; }
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum(T &v, Ts... rest) {
    return v + sum(rest...);
}
```

Usage -

```
int a = sum(1,2,3);
```

Requirement -

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
sum(1,2,3,a); // Need to pass array of same type and get the result.
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want to expand `a` in `sum(1, 2, 3, a)` to have `sum(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)` ?

Comment: Well, the expansion should happen automatically. It is like having the sum of int,int,int*. So I guess, I should get the first and last index if the given type is array and return the sum for other elements to use it.

Comment: Even the expansion will work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(const T& v) { return v; }

// special case for array    
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T sum(const T (&v)[N]) { return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), T{}); }

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum(const T& v, const Ts&... rest) {
    return sum(v) + sum(rest...);
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/17YLlN)

Comment: If you add an overload for `std::vector`, it works also [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/sU8JtS). If you don't want to write specific code for each container, it is possible but it is more complicated [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/85P1md).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few `const` and reference related errors, as well as attempting to instantiate the `same` template with an invalid number of arguments.

To fix this, you need to make your recursive template take two explicit arguments so that you never instantiate `same` with an empty parameter pack:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct same {
    using type = typename same<T, typename same<Ts...>::type>::type;
};
template <typename T>
struct same<T, T> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
T sum(const T &v) { return v; }

template <typename T, typename TT, typename... Ts>
typename same<T, TT, Ts...>::type sum(const T &v, const TT &w, const Ts&... rest) {
    return sum(v) + sum(w,rest...);
}
```

Then, if you want to still use your `same` construct, but also support array unpacking, something like this should work:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct same {
    using type = typename same<T, typename same<Ts...>::type>::type;
};
template <typename T>
struct same<T, T> {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct same<T, T[N]> {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct same<T[N], T[N]> {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct same<T[N], T> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
T sum(const T &v) { return v; }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T sum(const T (&v)[N]) { 
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), T{});
}

template <typename T, typename TT, typename... Ts>
typename same<T, TT, Ts...>::type sum(const T &v, const TT &w, const Ts&... rest) {
    return sum(v) + sum(w,rest...);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Zjknqc)

You could improve that solution by adding perfect forwarding and trying to eliminate the necessity for `T` to be default constructable.

Comment: I edited my code. But thank you for the time and making me understand. Really appreciate this. Also, What could be the condition, If I Include Containers in this. Like Vector.

Comment: You would need to extend `same` to accept standard containers and add another version of `sum` to support them. You could probably use expression SFINAE to define the sum function. Something like `decltype(std::begin(v), std::end(v), T{})` to see if something acts like a container.

Comment: You could do some canonicalisation of types with some helper traits.